# How to test for a returned Object in Unit testing in Java, BlueJ?

Tags: java, unit-testing, object, junit, bluej

So let's assume I have a class in Java called ItemClass and I'm calling one of the methods in the class which returns an object of type Feedback where Feedback is another class.

Now, how can I test if the returned object from the ItemClass is a specific Feedback which I have created previously.

How can I also test if the returned Object is null if there is no Feedback?

I am using BlueJ JUnit testing.

Comment: Are you aware of `assertNull()` and `assetNotNull()`?

Comment: What do you mean by “a specific Feedback”? The exact same instance, or  the “same” using its equality criteria (e.g., a unique ID or a combination of attributes)?

Answer (score 0):

assertNull() Can help you determine whether it is null， and instanceof Can help you determine whether a object belongs to a certain class

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).